# How to insert 1000 unique strings (URL) in the array field of each document in the collection?

Tags: javascript, json, mongoose

I have a collection called "houses" with 200 documents in mongoDb. Each house document has "images" field(array).

I would like to know how can I insert a list/array/json of 1000 unique url's to the field "images"(array[5]) ? .5 url's to each house, so every house can have 5 different images.

```
{
   "_id": {
        "$oid": "605f7bfa805fab1ba0611b79"
    },
 
  "pics": ["http://dummyimage.com/640x480.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
 "http://dummyimage.com/640x480.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
 "http://dummyimage.com/640x480.png/5fa2dd/ffffff",
 "http://dummyimage.com/640x480.png/dddddd/000000",
 "http://dummyimage.com/640x480.png/ff4444/ffffff"],
}
```

Right now it has some dummy images from mockaroo , but I wanna put real images I got from an online api.